# Capture CPU and Memory usage dynamically

Tags: c++, performance, shell, memory-management, cpu-usage

I am running a shell script to execute a c++ application, which measures the performance of an api. i can capture the latency (time taken to return a value for a given set of parameters) of the api, but i also wish to capture the cpu and memory usage alongside at intervals of say 5-10 seconds.

is there a way to do this without effecting the performance of the system too much and that too within the same script? i have found many examples where one can do outside (independently) of the script we are running; but not one where we can do within the same script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux (Ubuntu)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt)

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功: that question was asked later than this one, and would be a duplicate, not this one :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use '[time](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time)' command and also '[vmstat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vmstat)' command. The first will give CPU usage of executable execution and second - periodic (i.e. once per second) dump of CPU/memory/IO of the system.

Example:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero bs=1K of=/dev/null count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 0.738194 seconds, 1.4 GB/s
0.218u 0.519s 0:00.73 98.6%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w <== that's time result
```

Comment: could you provide an example? i tried the same within shell, but it expects the process to get over and i have multiple instances of the call running in the same script ... written one line after the other.

Comment: I added an example, i think you'll need to collect the output and sum it manually. Another suggestion to make all the runs in one script and do 'time' for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for capturing CPU and Mem utilization dynamically for entire linux box, then following command can help you too:

**CPU**

```
vmstat -n 15 10| awk '{now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print now $0}'> CPUDataDump.csv &
```

`vmstat` is used for collection of CPU counters

`-n` for delay value, in this case it's 15, that means after every 15 sec, stats will be collected.

then `10` is the number of intervals, there would be 10 iterations in this example

`awk '{now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print now $0}'` this will dump the timestamp of each iteration

in the end, the dump file with `&`  for continuation

**Memory**

```
free -m -s 10 10 | awk '{now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print now $0}'> DataDumpMemoryfile.csv &
```

`free` is for mem stats collection

`-m` this is for units of mem (you can use `-b` for bytes, `-k` for kilobytes, `-g` for gigabytes)

then `10` is the number of intervals (there would be 10 iterations in this example)

`awk'{now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print now $0}'` this will dump the timestamp of each iteration

in the end, the dump `&` for continuation