# Retrieve CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, memory-management, cpu-usage

I want to get the CPU and memory usage of a single process on Linux - I know the PID.  Hopefully, I can get it every second and write it to a CSV using the 'watch' command.  What command can I use to get this info from the Linux command-line?

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: Can we use gdb to call getpid and top -p <that pid>?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

(You can leave off "cmd" but that might be helpful in debugging).

Note that this gives average CPU usage of the process over the time it has been running.

Comment: This isn't very accurate. It includes the memory used by shared libraries.

Comment: The assumption would be that if you care about a single processes' memory usage enough to monitor it like this, it's using a significant amount of memory so that the extra couple-of-megabytes due to shared mappings isn't an issue.

Comment: @Chaitanya: pipe it through `| tail -n +2`

Comment: Or you could use --noheader

Comment: Keep in mind that %cpu "is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage" (see manpage of `ps`). This is _not_ the real just in time CPU usage. It can also be very different from what `top` shows, for instance.

Comment: as said from Xebeche just above, `ps -e -o pcpu,args` will show the cpu average over the lifetime of the process, which is obviously not what you want if it is a long running process

Comment: `while true; do ps -p 20283 -o %cpu,%mem,cmd; sleep 1; done;`

Get a continuous status every second.

Comment: What if the process is very short-lived?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: Well, in that case it's probably pretty uninteresting.  You could find the total CPU time used by running it under `time`, for memory you'd need to use a memory profiler like valgrind's massif tool.

Comment: Does the command return cpu usage percentage of all cores? For example if I got 30% cpu usage and I have 10 cores, it means that 3 cores are busy? Thanks.

Comment: @EvgenyA. No, 100% on the `%cpu` measure is one CPU (on average, over the process lifetime), so with a multithreaded process the number can be greater than 100%.

Comment: This is not the cpu usage in for current situation, and it is misleading others, can you specify this point in your answer, thanks.

Comment: what should I do if I have multiple `pid`s

Comment: @cizixs, why not use watch -n1 'ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd' instead of the while loop?

Answer (score 84):

A variant of [caf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221597/13326):
`top -p <pid>`

This auto-refreshes the CPU usage so it's good for monitoring.

Comment: Works nicely with `pgrep`: `top -p $(pgrep process_name)`

Comment: top: bad pid process_name

Comment: @MatthiasBraun should be `top -p $(pgrep -d',' process_name)` please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710740/2402577

Answer (score 73):

`ps` command (should not use):

- [CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#NOTES)

`top` command (should use):

- [The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html#3._FIELDS_/_Columns)

Use `top` to get CPU usage in real time(current short interval):

`top -b -n 2 -d 0.2 -p 6962 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`

will echo like: `78.6`

- `-b`: Batch-mode
- `-n 2`: Number-of-iterations, use `2` because: [When you first run it, it has no previous
  sample to compare to, so these initial values are the percentages since boot.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619#c3)
- `-d 0.2`: Delay-time(in second, here is 200ms)
- `-p 6962`: Monitor-PIDs
- `tail -1`: the last row
- `awk '{print $9}'`: the 9-th column(the cpu usage number)

Comment: This is the most accurate answer to get the current CPU usage, not an average over the lifetime of the process.

Comment: warning: column order is subject to your ~/.toprc, see `pidstat` below

Comment: this only returns %CPU

Answer (score 45):

You can get the results by the name of the process using

```
ps -C chrome -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

the `-C` option allows you to use process name without knowing it's pid.

Comment: how to include also de pid? ihave tried %pid $PID pid, PID with no luck

Comment: @ArnoldRoa `pid` only should work. `ps -C chrome -o pid,%cpu,%mem,cmd`

Comment: this does not work in unix

Comment: can list multiple processes with `ps -C chrome,nginx `

Comment: `ps` command returns average load for PROCESS LIFETIME

Answer (score 44):

Use pidstat (from sysstat - [Refer Link](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html)).

e.g. to monitor these two process IDs (12345 and 11223) every 5 seconds use

```
$ pidstat -h -r -u -v -p 12345,11223 5
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out `pidstat` that's a great command, and handy too for scripting!

Comment: `pidstat` also gives a nice average.  just a shame i have not found a more elegant way of `pidstat -u 1 10 | grep ^Average | sort -r -n -b -k 8,8`

Answer (score 22):

**Launch a program and monitor it**

This form is useful if you want to benchmark an executable easily:

```
topp() (
  if [ -n "$O" ]; then
    $* &
  else
    $* &>/dev/null &
  fi
  pid="$!"
  trap "kill $pid" SIGINT
  o='%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss'
  printf '%s\n' "$o"
  i=0
  while s="$(ps --no-headers -o "$o" -p "$pid")"; do
    printf "$i $s\n"
    i=$(($i + 1))
    sleep "${T:-0.1}"
  done
)
```

Usage:

```
topp ./myprog arg1 arg2
```

Sample output:

```
%cpu,%mem,vsz
0  0.0  0.0 177584
1  0.0  0.1 588024
2  0.0  0.1 607084
3  0.0  0.2 637248
4  0.0  0.2 641692
5 68.0  0.2 637904
6 80.0  0.2 642832
```

where vsz is the total memory usage in KiB, e.g. the above had about 600MiB usage.

If your program finishes, the loop stops and we exit `topp`.

Alternatively, if you git Ctrl + C, the program also stops due to the `trap`: [How do I kill background processes / jobs when my shell script exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits)

The options are:

- `T=0.5 topp ./myprog`: change poll interval
- `O=1 topp ./myprog`: don't hide program stdout/stderr. This can be useful to help correlate at which point memory usage bursts with stdout.

**`ps` vs `top` on instantaneous CPU% usage**

Note that the CPU usage given by `ps` above is not "instantaneous" (i.e. over the last N seconds), but rather the average over the processes' entire lifetime as mentioned at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result `ps` memory measures should be fine however.

That thread as well as: [How can I determine the current CPU utilization from the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332861/how-can-i-determine-the-current-cpu-utilization-from-the-shell/1332955#1332955) suggest that the Linux kernel does not store any more intermediate usage statistics, so the only way to do that would be to poll and calculate for the previous period, which is what `top` does.

We could therefore use `top -n1` instead of `ps` if we wanted that:

```
toppp() (
  $* &>/dev/null &
  pid="$!"
  trap exit SIGINT
  i=1
  top -b n1 -d "${T:-0.1}" -n1 -p "$pid"
  while true; do top -b n1 -d "${T:-0.1}" -n1 -p "$pid"  | tail -1; printf "$i "; i=$(($i + 1)); done
)
```

as mentioned e.g. at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421136/895245 which produces output of type:

```
top - 17:36:59 up  9:25, 12 users,  load average: 0.32, 1.75, 2.21
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.4 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31893.7 total,  13904.3 free,  15139.8 used,   2849.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  16005.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 706287 ciro      20   0  590436  40352  20568 R 106.7   0.1   0:00.16 node
 706287 ciro      20   0  607060  57172  21340 R 126.7   0.2   0:00.35 node
1  706287 ciro      20   0  642008  80276  21812 R 113.3   0.2   0:00.52 node
2  706287 ciro      20   0  641676  93108  21812 R 113.3   0.3   0:00.70 node
3  706287 ciro      20   0  647892  99956  21812 R 106.7   0.3   0:00.87 node
4  706287 ciro      20   0  655980 109564  21812 R 140.0   0.3   0:01.09 node
```

Some related threads:

- how to run `top` just once (`-b -n1`)

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/484510/how-to-run-top-command-1-time-and-exit
  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/how-to-stream-top-snapshot-into-file asks about
- how to remove the headers from `top`: no one has a better solution so we just `tail` it:

  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471072/how-to-remove-top-commands-header
  - [How to suppress the general information for top command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995380/how-to-suppress-the-general-information-for-top-command)

My only problems with this is that `top` is not as nice for interactive usage:

- Ctrl + C does not exit the above command, not sure why `trap exit` is not working as it does with `ps`. I have to kill the command `Ctrl + \`, and then that does not kill the process itself which continues to run on the background, which means that if it is an infinite loop like a server, I have to `ps aux` and then kill it.
- the not exit automatically when the benchmarked program exits

Maybe someone more shell savvy than me can find a solution for those.

`ps` memory measurements should be the same as `top` however if you're just after memory.

Related:

- [Retrieve CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process

Tested on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: shoudn't it be `topp() { .. }`

Comment: @alper `toppp` is a different command than `topp` ;-) The naming convention is glorious I must say.

Comment: Is it a bash function? I was not able to make it work

Comment: @alper yes. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 now with `toppp stress-ng --vm 8 --vm-bytes 80% -t 5`. What's your error?

Comment: Ah I was in `zsh` that's why I was not able to make it work

Comment: Somewhat funny: the "Retrieve CPU..." link at the end is to this very question :)

Comment: @pglpm it's because I sometimes copy answers across sites and forget to update related section. But at least it is true nonetheless given the reflexivity of relatedness.

Comment: Happened to me too a couple of times, noticing it last minute :) I'm sure no reader got stuck in an infinite referential loop :D Thank you for the excellent informative answer by the way! (I mean the answer to the OP)

Comment: You can fix the stopping issues (Ctrl+C and program exit) by changing your while loop condition from just 'true' to `test -d /proc/"$pid"/`, this way the loop will exit when your program ends.

Answer (score 6):

As commented in [caf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221597/13326) above, ps and in some cases pidstat will give you the lifetime average of the pCPU.
To get more accurate results use top. If you need to run top once you can run:

```
top -b -n 1 -p <PID>
```

or for process only data and header:

```
top -b -n 1 -p <PID> | tail -3 | head -2
```

without headers:

```
top -b -n 1 -p <PID> | tail -2 | head -1
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `top -b` and grep out the pid you want (with the `-b` flag top runs in batch mode), or also use the `-p` flag and specify the pid without using grep.

Answer (score 4):

For those who struggled for a while wonderring why the selected answer does not work:

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem
```

No SPACE ibetween `%cpu,` and `%mem`.

Answer (score 4):

The following command gets the average of CPU and memory usage every 40 seconds for a specific process(pid)

```
pidstat 40 -ru -p <pid>
```

Output for my case(first two lines for CPU usage, second two lines for memory):

```
02:15:07 PM       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
02:15:47 PM     24563    0.65    0.07    0.00    0.73     3  java

02:15:07 PM       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
02:15:47 PM     24563      6.95      0.00 13047972 2123268   6.52  java
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ps aux | awk '{print $4"\t"$11}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1" "$3}' | sort -nr
```

or per process

```
ps aux | awk '{print $4"\t"$11}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1" "$3}' | sort -nr |grep mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ps axo pid,etime,%cpu,%mem,cmd | grep 'processname' | grep -v grep
```

PID - Process ID

etime - Process Running/Live Duration

%cpu - CPU usage

%mem - Memory usage

cmd - Command

Replace processname with whatever process you want to track, mysql nginx php-fpm etc ...

Answer (score 2):

Above list out the top cpu and memory consuming process

```
        ps axo %cpu,%mem,command | sort -nr | head
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers here show only the memory percentage for the PID.

Here's an example of how to get the rss memory usage in KB for all apache processes, replace "grep apache" with "grep PID" if you just want to watch a specific PID:

```
watch -n5 "ps aux -y | grep apache | awk '{print \$2,\$6}'"
```

This prints:

```
Every 5.0s: ps aux -y | grep apache | awk '{print $2,$6}'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Thu Jan 25 15:44:13 2018

12588 9328
12589 8700
12590 9392
12591 9340
12592 8700
12811 15200
15453 9340
15693 3800
15694 2352
15695 1352
15697 948
22896 9360
```

With CPU %:

```
watch -n5 "ps aux -y | grep apache | awk '{print \$2,\$3,\$6}'"
```

Output:

```
Every 5.0s: ps aux -y | grep apache | awk '{print $2,$3,$6}'                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Thu Jan 25 15:46:00 2018

12588 0.0 9328
12589 0.0 8700
12590 0.0 9392
12591 0.0 9340
12592 0.0 8700
12811 0.0 15200
15453 0.0 9340
15778 0.0 3800
15779 0.0 2352
15780 0.0 1348
15782 0.0 948
22896 0.0 9360
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the memory usage of just your application (as opposed to the shared libraries it uses, you need to use the Linux smaps interface). [This answer explains it well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860878/tracking-actively-used-memory-in-linux-programs/872456#872456).

Answer (score 1):

(If you are in MacOS 10.10, try the accumulative -c option of top:

```
top -c a -pid PID
```

(This option is not available in other linux, tried with Scientific Linux el6 and RHEL6)

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux|awk  '{print $2,$3,$4}'|grep PID
```

where the first column  is the PID,second column CPU usage ,third column memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice trick to follow one or more programs in real time while also watching some other tool's output:
    `watch "top -bn1 -p$(pidof foo),$(pidof bar); tool"`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @caf's answer, this working nicely for me.

Calculate average for given PID:

**measure.sh**

```
times=100
total=0
for i in $(seq 1 $times)
do
   OUTPUT=$(top -b -n 1 -d 0.1 -p $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')
   echo -n "$i time: ${OUTPUT}"\\r
   total=`echo "$total + $OUTPUT" | bc -l`
done
#echo "Average: $total / $times" | bc

average=`echo "scale=2; $total / $times" | bc`
echo "Average: $average"
```

Usage:

```
# send PID as argument
sh measure.sh 3282
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751050/2194843) we can estimate the average CPU and memory utilization of a specific process for a specific amount of time by collecting `N samples` with `sampling period T` as follows:

```
N=3;
T=1;
PROCESS_NAME="my_proc";

top -b -c -n $(let tmp=N+1; echo $tmp) -d ${T} -p $(pgrep ${PROCESS_NAME}) | 
grep ${PROCESS_NAME} |  
tee /var/tmp/foo.log |
tail -n +2 | 
awk -v N=$N 'BEGIN{
                c=0; 
                m=0
            }{
                c=c+$9; 
                m=m+$10
            }END{
                printf("%s %s\n", c/N, m/N) 
            }';
```

In order to be able to evaluate the results we are collecting the output of the top into the `/var/tmp/foo.log` file. The expected output is something like this:

```
2.33333 6.9
```

And the content of our log file:

```
196918 root      20   0   24.4g   1.3g 113872 S   0.0   6.9  39:58.15 my_proc
196918 root      20   0   24.4g   1.3g 113872 S   2.0   6.9  39:58.17 my_proc
196918 root      20   0   24.4g   1.3g 113872 S   3.0   6.9  39:58.20 my_proc
196918 root      20   0   24.4g   1.3g 113872 S   2.0   6.9  39:58.22 my_proc
```

Note that we ignore (`tail -n +2`) the first execution of the top command.

Answer (score 1):

I use htop

```
sudo apt install htop
htop
```

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search the process you are interested in and remember the PID. Quit with <kbd>q</kbd> and start htop again showing the process you want only

```
htop -p $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Neon answer, my two cents here:

```sh
pidstat -h -r -u -v -p $(ps aux | grep <process name> | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ',')
```