# Debian: Find out CPU usage using bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm using PHP to read the current CPU usage. I'm on a vServer, so shell_exec is enabled.

I have tried `grep` on `ps`, but it didn't work.
How can I read the current % CPU usage using bash?

Comment: would load average from bash suffice? `cat /proc/loadavg` also, http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html (sysstat) may be something you might want to use/install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is simply to use [sys_getloadavg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

If you want to directly ask the OS, use uptime

```
$uptimeString = `uptime`;
```

Or any of the [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332861/how-can-i-determine-the-current-cpu-utilization-from-the-shell) to how to do exactly the same thing in bash and just wrap in backticks.

Comment: I've seen the getLoadAvg commande before, but it's not the same as CPU usage (%). Both uptime and getloadavg could be interesting, too. But how can I find out the CPU usage?

Comment: have you read the existing answers - e.g. the first answer in the question I linked to?

Comment: Oh wait a moment. It always shows the same values, except if I wait for a few seconds. My PHP script always reads the same values...

Answer (score 3):

After taking a closer look at all solutions, I came up with this code:

```
<?php
    exec('ps -aux', $processes);
    foreach($processes as $process)
    {
        $cols = split(' ', ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $process));
        if (strpos($cols[2], '.') > -1)
        {
            $cpuUsage += floatval($cols[2]);
        }
    }
    print($cpuUsage);
?>
```

It calls `ps -aux` and sums up the CPU %.