# How to know how much Ram and how many CPU are available for a Linux/Plesk Vps?

Tags: linux, apache, vps

is it possible to know how much Ram and how many CPU are available for a Linux/Plesk Vps using a php script?

Answer (score 0):

I think phpsysinfo would work for you. phpSysInfo is a open source PHP script that displays host information.

http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/

As an alternative solution, you can set cron job to run php script that will store the CPU and RAM information. For more information, refer following thread:

[Get cpu percent usage in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131003/get-cpu-percent-usage-in-php)