# Calculating CPU usage % in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cpu

Is the CPU utilization percent calculated by computing `100 - idle%` when using `mpstat` to calculate the average CPU usage? Is this correct or do I have to compute the CPU utilization in any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Check this, It may help:

[How to get overall CPU Usage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the current CPU utilization from the shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332861/how-can-i-determine-the-current-cpu-utilization-from-the-shell)