# Filter by process name and log CPU usage

Tags: linux, unix

Is there an option for the Linux [top command](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) where I can filter processes by name and write the CPU usage of that process every second to a log file?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## `top` & `pgrep`

To filter the output of [`top`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) by process name, you can use  [`pgrep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) to get a list of [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)s by process name then pass them to the `-p` option of `top`.

For example:

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' http)
```

Note: the `-d','` option delimits the PIDs with commas, which is what is expected by the `top -p`.
Note 2: `top` will return a failure message if there are no running processes that match the name you specify in `pgrep`.

To write the results of `top` to a file, use the `-n 1` option (only one iteration) and redirect the output to your log file.

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' http) -n 1 >> your_log_file
```

To do that every second, perhaps a `while` loop with a `sleep` would do?

```
while :; do top -p $(pgrep -d',' http) -n 1 >> your_log_file; sleep 1; done
```

---

To timestamp each entry, you can append the output of `date`. E.g.

```
while :; do top -p $(pgrep -d',' http) -n 1 >> log.txt; date >> log.txt; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, how to log date & time for each 1 second., So that it would help me isolate at what time and how much CPU was used by specific process.

Comment: @melihcelik which task are you referring to?

Comment: I thought all of them would print with similar format, sorry. I was referring to this command: top -p $(pgrep -d',' http). I tried to read the output in Windows, didn't work. Tried to read it with more (less) on linux, didn't work either. I can only open it with vi.

Comment: The command "`top -p $(pgrep -d',' http)`" prints its output to stdout so you should not need any additional command to read the output. If there are no output, that just means there isn't a process that contains `http`. The following commands redirect that output to a file (note the "`>> filename`" statement) in which case you will need to read the file.

Comment: Excellent! I added also the "-b" option to avoid useless output confusing the file

Comment: I am getting `-p requires argument`

Comment: **Invalid argument "-p".**

Comment: I too get a `Illegal variable name.` on FreeBSD 11.2.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is:

```
top -b -d 1 -p $(pgrep -d',' java) -n 120 > log.txt
```

- The option -d allows to set the frequency used by top to refresh the
  data.
- The option -b means that the traditional interface of top is
  not used. Instead, it sends everything to the standard output and then you can use a pipe (|) or a redirection (>).
- The option -n informs about the number of iterations top should execute.

After that you can type:

```
cat log.txt | grep USER_OF_PROCESS
```

You will see the execution time of the process and also %CPU, Memory and all that.

Comment: **Invalid argument "-b".**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, weird, the option is still there, I think (https://linux.die.net/man/1/top)

Answer (score 2):

```
#You can run following script as ./cpurecorder.sh pid filename
#It will generate output file with memory usage and cpu utilisation.
#You can log other variable by searching man for ps.

`enter code here`filepath=/home/rtcsadm              # modify as desired
interval=20                         # reports per minute
timelimit=6000                      # how long to run, in seconds

mydate=`date "+%H:%M:%S"`           # the timestamp
freq=$((60/$interval))              # for sleep function

while [ "$SECONDS" -le "$timelimit" ] ; do
  ps -p$1 -opid -opcpu -opmem -ocomm -c | grep $1 | sed "s/^/$mydate /" >> $filepath/$2.txt
  sleep 3
  mydate=`date "+%H:%M:%S"`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the linux command "top"...

Then press the 'o' or 'O' to activate filter prompt. It will show a line indicating the filter format like this -

```
        add filter #1 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL
```

Then enter a filter like this and hit Enter.

```
               COMMAND=<pattern>
```

Now top will show only those processes whose COMMAND field contains the "<pattern>" value

(Solution taken from ... https://techantidote.com/filter-top-using-process-name-in-linux/ )