# Shell script to log CPU usage of a particular process without using ps aux

Tags: linux, memory, logging, scripting, ps

I am using a custom fedora distro, which does not support ps aux, hence I am finding it difficult to log the CPU usage of a particular process, is there an alternate way to measure the CPU usage apart from top or ps aux? calculating CPU usage from /proc//status would be great.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is to make the *parent* of the process call `getrusage()`. In fact, your process might call it itself periodically and log the values.