# Accessing process object from child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

When I spawn a process with `var proc = child_process.spawn("/usr/sbin/long_running_binary")`, I would like to have access to information about `proc` as its own process. I can run [`process.cpuUsage`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cpuusage_previousvalue) and [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) and [`process.uptime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime) for the current node process, but how do I find this metadata for `proc`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Node.js has a built-in way for you to do that.

I would spawn another process to check on the process you spawned using the process id:
`proc.pid`

Example command for getting pid usage in Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221597/536950

Comment: I need a cross-platform answer for this, not just limited to Linux, but spanning BSD and OSX as well. I didn't have a Linux tag on this question for this reason.