# Is there a formular to calculate CPU consumption by Docker deamon?

Tags: docker, containers

I acknowledge that besides an amount of CPU used by container alone, there is a marginal CPU used by other Docker services such as **Dockerd, Docker-client, Containerd**. 
But how can I measure them?

I can track down these processes using Top which showed that **Dockerd** CPU usage jump up or jump down unpredictable.

Moreover, it seems the more number of containers I run, the bigger CPU usage by **Dockerd**.

If so, is there an approximate number of **Dockerd** CPU usage per container?

or could anyone show me a way to measure them properly?

***PS: I know `docker-stats` could give us some resources parameter including CPU, but it doesn't show CPu usage by `Dockerd` and `Docker-client`, or I am mistaken?***

Comment: have you tried **docker stats** command. Other than this there are many ways based on **prometheus** and **Cdvisor**. Check for all those keywords and see which works better for you based on use-case.

Comment: try "docker stats"   it will give you data for all running containers.

Comment: i know about docker-stats, thanks anyway. But imo, it just shows you how much cpu used by container alone, not about other services like dockerd, etc.

Comment: You watch the CPU consumption of every process you want with something like this: [Retrieve CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux). Another interesting place to look is `/proc/<process_id>/stat`.