# How to get CPU and Memory usage by a process on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: shell, terminal

like many users I have several background processes.
I should only display in the terminal the % of CPU used and the RAM Memory used by a particular process.
How can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux